# Obtener la descripción de un Enum en una consulta linq

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio-2017

Trabajo con C#, Visual Studio 2019
Tengo la siguiente consulta

```
var result = from ov in context.OrdenVentas
                         join c in context.Clientes on ov.ClienteId equals c.ClienteId
                         where
                             (filter.Codigo == null || ov.CodigoNumerico.Contains(filter.Codigo))
                             &&
                             (!filter.ClienteId.HasValue || ov.ClienteId.Equals(filter.ClienteId.Value))
                             &&
                             (filter.FechaEmision == null || ov.FechaEmision >= filter.FechaEmision)
                             &&
                             (filter.FechaCaducidad == null || ov.FechaCaducidad <= filter.FechaCaducidad)
                             &&
                             ov.Estado == EstadoOrdenVenta.Emitido
                         select
                             new UniversalExtend()
                             {
                                 Id = ov.OrdenVentaId,
                                 NumeroComprobante = ov.NumeroComprobante,
                                 Descripcion = c.RazonSocial,
                                 FechaEmision = ov.FechaEmision,
                                 FechaCaducidad = ov.FechaCaducidad,
                                 Estado = 
                                 Total = ov.Total
                             };
            return result.ToList();
```

En estado necesito obtener la descripción de un enum.

En el campo EstadoId(en la db) tengo los valores del enum ahora quiero recuperarlo en una variable estado de tipo string, ¿como puedo leer la descripcion de un enum pasandole un campo ov.Estado el cual tiene el id del enum?

```
public enum EstadoOrdenVenta : int
{
    [Description("EMITIDO")]
    Emitido = 1,
    [Description("APROBADO")]
    Aprobado = 2,
    [Description("ATENDIDO")]
    Atendido = 3
}
```

Solo quiero obtener lo que esta en minúscula.

```
Estado = Enum.GetName(typeof(EstadoOrdenVenta), ov.Estado),
```

De esta manera tengo el siguiente error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String
>   GetName(System.Type, System.Object)' method, and this method cannot be
>   translated into a store expression.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Lo solucione de la siguiente manera

Implemete esta función que se encarga de leer la descripcion del Enum.

```
public string GetDescription(Enum value)
    {
        return
            value
                .GetType()
                .GetMember(value.ToString())
                .FirstOrDefault()
                ?.GetCustomAttribute<DescriptionAttribute>()
                ?.Description
            ?? value.ToString();
    }
```

Implemente una propiedad de solo lectura.

```
public EstadoOrdenVenta EstadoId { get; set; }

    public string EstadoDescripcion
    {
        get { return _helper.GetDescription(this.EstadoId); }
    }
    public decimal Total { get; set; }
```

De esta manera solo hago uso de la propiedad EstadoDescripcion donde quiero ver la información que trae.

Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Al momento de hacer .ToList() Entity framework intentara crear la sentencia SQL equivalente a tu query de la variable *result* ahi el detalle es que  el método `GetName` del Enum no tiene su equivalente en `sql`, es mejor que obtengas el nombre del Enum fuera del query y utilices el string ya que es un dato primitivo.

```
var estado= Enum.GetName(typeof(EstadoOrdenVenta), EstadoOrdenVenta.Emitido);

var result = from ov in context.OrdenVentas
                         join c in context.Clientes on ov.ClienteId equals c.ClienteId
                         where
                             (filter.Codigo == null || ov.CodigoNumerico.Contains(filter.Codigo))
                             &&
                             (!filter.ClienteId.HasValue || ov.ClienteId.Equals(filter.ClienteId.Value))
                             &&
                             (filter.FechaEmision == null || ov.FechaEmision >= filter.FechaEmision)
                             &&
                             (filter.FechaCaducidad == null || ov.FechaCaducidad <= filter.FechaCaducidad)
                             &&
                             ov.Estado.ToString() == estado
                         select
                             new UniversalExtend()
                             {
                                 Id = ov.OrdenVentaId,
                                 NumeroComprobante = ov.NumeroComprobante,
                                 Descripcion = c.RazonSocial,
                                 FechaEmision = ov.FechaEmision,
                                 FechaCaducidad = ov.FechaCaducidad,
                                 Estado = 
                                 Total = ov.Total
                             };
            return result.ToList();
```

Detalle:

```
 //Aquí tu código, no obtiene la descripción sino el nombre del Enum:
 Estado = Enum.GetName(typeof(EstadoOrdenVenta), ov.Estado),
```

Para obtener la descripción del Enum se usa reflexion: [Enum Description](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/157871/method-that-returns-description-attribute-of-enum-value)

Por otro lado tengo entendido que EF tolera comparar enum variables en las condicionales de los querys sin problemas, en tu caso no deberias tener problemas usando:

```
 ov.Estado == EstadoOrdenVenta.Emitido
```

Comment: Necesito mostrarlo en el select exactamente en la propiedad estado de tipo string mas no en la condición

Comment: La manera que lo planteas si funciona pero estaría quemando el código

Comment: De acuerdo pense que era en la condicion, de todas manera la funcion *getname* te iba a traer problemas, si lo necesitas en el select solo hazle un ov.Estado.Tostring()